# get the latitude and longitude from the xml url using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Here is my `jQuery ajax` :-

```
function getlg(){
    var cntry_code = 'IN';
    var reg = 'Rajkot';
    var xml;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+reg+"&country="+cntry_code+"",
        async: false,
        dataType:'xml',
        success: function(data)
        {
            xml=data;
        }
    });
    var lat = $(xml).find('lat:eq(0)').text();
    alert(lat);
    var lng = $(xml).find('lng:eq(0)').text();  
    alert(lng);
}
```

I am trying to pass in URL city name and country code and get `xml` file.
try jsfiddle :-http://jsfiddle.net/GbDFD/
From this `xml` file i am try to get first `lat` and `lng` element value.

This is **[working url](http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address=Rajkot&country=IN)**.

I am try to pass the city name and country code in ajax url its work but not return me latitude and longitude value.

how can it work using javascript.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `jsonp` , For that you need to include `format=json` in your url

```
"http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+reg+"&country="+cntry_code+"&format=json"
```

Here is the working Code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address=" + reg + "&country=" + cntry_code + "&format=json",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
           var lat = data.result[0].lat;
           console.log(lat);
           var lng = data.result[0].lng;
           console.log(lng);
       }
});
```

Demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/GbDFD/1/

Comment: hi i am try to both lat and lng variable globally and try this     `success: function (data) {
           lat = data.result[0].lat;
           console.log(lat);
           lng = data.result[0].lng;
           console.log(lng);
       }
    
});    

var data1 = lat+","+lng; 
   console.log('out' + data1);
}` but its return undefined.

Comment: The reason , why this will not work that way is because `jsonp` is incompatible with `async`, so you cannot use `async:false` as this has no effect on how jsonp works