# get xml element value using url xml

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I am trying to get city data from the xml file.
Below one is a url of XML response from which I am getting a latitude and longitude value from the XML response/file.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Kenya&sensor=true

and this is my JavaScript code:-

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function load(){
        var reg = "Kenya";
                alert(reg);
                var xml;
                $.ajax({
                  url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+reg+"&sensor=true",
                  async: false,
                  dataType:'xml',
                  success: function(data)
                {
                    xml=data;
                }
            });
                var lat = $(xml).find('lat:eq(0)').text();
                var lng = $(xml).find('lng:eq(0)').text();  
                var radius = "100000";
                alert(lat);
                alert(lng);
                 $.ajax({
              url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&radius="+radius+"&format=json",
              async: false,
              dataType:'jsonp',
              success: function(data)
            {
                var asciiname = data.result[0].asciiName;
                console.log(asciiname);
            }
        });
            }
</script>
<body onload="load()">
</body>
```

with this I am trying to pass Region name in above url with lat and lang value.

http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=-0.0235590&lng=37.9061930&radius=100000.

With this url I am trying to get asciiName.
But it's not working and itss display nothing.
What I am doing wrong. Help me to solve my problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: you have XML Parsing Error in second ajax.

Comment: You need to write proper sentences (with correct grammar) so that anybody can get the idea  at first that what you want to convey?

Comment: @NullVoid sorry for my gammar mistake...

Comment: @BharatChodvadiya yes and i am try to dataType: 'jsonp',

Comment: I think you had also asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317128/get-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-the-xml-url-using-ajax/16317523#16317523) and it can solve your this issue.

Comment: @NullVoid check i am edited my second ajax with the reference of your link still not work

Comment: if i am remove first ajax then its work....

Comment: I am getting `Kotharia` as a result from your above code. Is this correct?

Comment: @NullVoid yes its correct

Comment: @NullVoid problem solve... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your full code details. You're missing some variables like `cntry_code` and `dataType` in `ajax` call. If your question is solved then accept it.

```
<script>
    function getlg(){
            var cntry_code = 'IN';
            var reg = 'Rajkot';
            var xml;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+reg+"&country="+cntry_code+"&format=json",
                async: false,
                dataType:'jsonp',
                success: function(data){ 
                    var id = data.result[1].id;
                    console.log(id);
                    var lat = data.result[1].lat;
                    console.log(lat);
                    var lng = data.result[1].lng;  
                    console.log(lng);
                    var radius = "100000";
                    $.ajax({
                          url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&radius="+radius+"&format=json",
                          async: false,
                          dataType:'jsonp',
                          success: function(data)
                          {
                                for(i=0;i<data.result.length;i++)
                                {
                                    var asciiname = data.result[i].asciiName;
                                    console.log(asciiname);
                                }
                          }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: how can get all asciiname?

Comment: I have updated the code. I have added `for loop` so that you get all asciiName(s).